# ContextMenu/MenuItem with icon on .NET Compact Framework 2.0 and Windows CE

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, menuitem

It seems that the `MenuItem` class on [.NET Compact Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework) (CF) 2.0 does not support icons. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menus in the CF are wrappers around the OS-supplied menu items, which do not support images/icons.  The only "workaround" would be to implement your own menuing system when you manually draw everything.  That's going to be a *lot* of work.  A [Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolbar%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is likely going to be an easier thing to work with if you need images.

Comment: The problem is that the .NET 2 desktop equivalent of the same app works and the CE app should be very similar. A own menu component will be hard because the element must overlap everything else on the form.

Comment: Just had a look at the device and the start menu uses kind of a contextmenu with icons. Do you think that mechanism would be possible to wrap around?

Comment: The start menu/title bar is it's own application.  The menu is fully custom-drawn so it's not something you can use in your own app.